# Datatool can't evaluate email as empty?

Tags: datatool, email

Given a test.csv file w/ the content:

```
"BILL TO EMAIL"
"test@att.net"
""
"test.test@test.org"
"test.test@test.org"
```

Processing it w/ datatool in xelatex w/:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{data}{test.csv}
\begin{document}
\DTLforeach*{data}{\billtoEM=BILL TO EMAIL}{\billtoEM"\DTLifnull{\billtoEM}{N}{Y}"\par}
\end{document}
```

results in:

[image: test YYYYY]

How do I get the test to evaluate to N for the second record?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a difference between null and empty values (in a similar way to programming languages `"" != null`). If you load data from a CSV file, missing values are empty. (There is a blank value in that column for that row.) Null values can occur when constructing a database where values for a column or columns aren't assigned. (For example, defining data using `\DTLnewdb` or pulling data from SQL using `datatooltk`.)

You can test for empty values using `etoolbox`'s `\ifdefempty`:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{datatool}
\DTLloaddb{data}{test.csv}
\begin{document}
\DTLforeach*{data}{\billtoEM=BILL TO EMAIL}{\billtoEM"\ifdefempty{\billtoEM}{N}{Y}"\par}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively you can use `\DTLifnullorempty` that tests for null or empty values.

Further details in 5.5 "Null Values" of the `datatool` user manual.

Comment: Thank you for your patience, and please accept my apologies for not finding that command in the manual.

Comment: @WillAdams That's okay. It's quite a common mistake. I ought to add it to the `datatool` faq.